# fragment switching - can't return from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, android-xml, android-scrollview

I'm trying to implement navigation between two fragments. One is default view for my app which contains only RecyclerView with its own items, and the other is ScrollView with TableLayout as a child. App properly switches from my `ViewAdverts` fragment to `AddAdvert`, but then when I want to go back there appears exception and app crashes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pl.polsl.elektr.quicktrade011, PID: 14676
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
    at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:248)
    at android.support.design.widget.BaseTransientBottomBar.showView(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:444)
    at android.support.design.widget.BaseTransientBottomBar$1.handleMessage(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:185)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I have no idea why that error appears only when returning from ScrollView to RecyclerView, and not on app start when the default fragment contains RecyclerView.
Here are my `.java` and `.xml` files:
[5 files at Gist](https://gist.github.com/multim0/8da8a8329d7e9898a465bde0bd3d231a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment A

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragment = new DashboardFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Fragment B

```
    rootview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    rootview.requestFocus();
    rootview.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                // DO WHAT YOU WANT ON BACK PRESSED
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, it resolved my problem. But I'm still curious why it throwed something connected with layouts (ScrollView - where is it even in this example?), not with fragment's backstack. I mean - how do you know, that above solution will repair it?